# How to find out if a certain character in a String is Uppercase

Tags: java, android, if-statement, break, continue

I checked all other stackoverflow links about my question but the answers there did not work. So I am asking a similar question with the hope of getting a different answer.
This is the code from a class:

```
public String pozisyonHazirla(String param) {

        String oynananHamle = param;   

        for (int n = 0; n < oynananHamle.length(); n++) {
            if (oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches("[0-9]") || oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches(".")) {

                String donothing="";

            } else if (oynananHamle.substring(n, 1) == oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).toUpperCase()) {

             sonuc = "Figür Hamlesi Yapıldı";
                break;

            } else {

                sonuc = "Piyon hamlesi yapıldı";
            break;
            }

                         }

            return sonuc;  
        }
```

The question is that this section of the code is not working and in 100% of the cases the iteration returns the else result which is the assigned value to the sonuc variable.

```
 } else if (oynananHamle.substring(n, 1) == oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).toUpperCase()) {

             sonuc = "Figür Hamlesi Yapıldı";
                break;
```

My second question without opening another thread is that in the first case there is  a section where I want nothing to be done if the "if" statement is viable so I put something like " String donothing ="";" . Is there anyway to improve this piece of code?
Thank you in advanace for your answers and comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I thank both of you. The answer is a mixture of both ideas and is as follows:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < oynananHamle.length(); i++) {
            char c = oynananHamle.charAt(i);
            //if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '.') {
               // continue; // go to next character
             if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                sonuc = "Figür Hamlesi Yapıldı :" + c + " "+i;
                 break;
            }
            if (!(c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c == '.')) {
                sonuc = "Piyon hamlesi yapıldı :" + c + " "+i;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Of course there is a return sonuc statement at the end. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `isUpperCase()` :

```
char c = 'A';
boolean upper = Character.isUpperCase(c); // true
```

Concerning that unused `doNothing` code block, change:

```
if (oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches("[0-9]") || oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches(".")) {
    String donothing="";
} else if (oynananHamle.substring(n, 1) == oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).toUpperCase()) {
    sonuc = "Figür Hamlesi Yapıldı";
    break;
} else {
    sonuc = "Piyon hamlesi yapıldı";
    break;
}
```

to

```
if (oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).equals(oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).toUpperCase())) {
    sonuc = "Figür Hamlesi Yapıldı";
    break;
}

if (!(oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches("[0-9]") || oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches(".")) {
    sonuc = "Piyon hamlesi yapıldı";
    break;
}
```

### EDIT:

(full code)

```
public String pozisyonHazirla(String param) {
    String oynananHamle = param;
    String sonuc = "";

    for (int n = 0; n < oynananHamle.length(); n++) {
        if (oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).equals(oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).toUpperCase())) {
            sonuc = "Figür Hamlesi Yapıldı";
            break;
        }

        if (!(oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches("[0-9]") || oynananHamle.substring(n, 1).matches(".")) {
            sonuc = "Piyon hamlesi yapıldı";
            break;
        }
    }

    return sonuc;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile.

Comment: @EJP you're right, a `String` declaration was missing, fixed it.

Comment: That's not all that is wrong. Have a look at your first two lines.

Comment: Thank you. It works now pls see my note for Karakuri ... Regards

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `==` does not compare the contents of strings, it just checks whether it is the same object reference. You need to use `.equals()` to compare the actual strings.

However you don't even need to do that since you can simply test the individual characters, which will be a lot more efficient than making substrings.

```
for (int i = 0; i < param.length(); i++) {
    char c = param.charAt(i);
    if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == '.') {
        continue; // go to next character
    } else if (Character.isUppercase(c)) {
        return "Figür Hamlesi Yapıldı";
    } else {
        return "Piyon hamlesi yapıldı";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It works as it stands above. Best Regards